# Cannot be owner of newly formated ext4 drive

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, hard-drive

I have read quite a few tips and tricks here and there on this forum. However, I cannot find any clean way of solving this problem. I had an old 1.5tb drive that was in a e-SATA box that I plugged in my computer on my Ubuntu 16.04. Struggled a bit to get the partition on it, succeeded and now have mounted my drive on:
/mnt/3b42e9ce-1972-498b-9b96-13199979c333

This is my setup:

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 1.4 TiB, 1500301910016 bytes, 2930277168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x06dd1f4e

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 2930276351 2930274304  1.4T 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdb: 279.4 GiB, 300000000000 bytes, 585937500 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x129228a1

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1              52     65675     65624    32M de Dell Utility
/dev/sdb2  *        67584  27645951  27578368  13.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb4        27645952 585936895 558290944 266.2G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5        27648000  35459071   7811072   3.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb6        35461120 113584127  78123008  37.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb7       113586176 585936895 472350720 225.2G 83 Linux
```

so sda 1 is my problem. 
I have tried this trick:

```
sudo chgrp USER /mnt/3b42e9ce-1972-498b-9b96-13199979c333
sudo chmod g+w /mnt/3b42e9ce-1972-498b-9b96-13199979c333
```

But this is not solving my problem my softwares cannot write on the disk. Not sure if I can really execute something on it. And this does not last after reboot and remounting. I have this message:

```
sudo chgrp USER /mnt/3b42e9ce-1972-498b-9b96-13199979c333
chgrp: changing group of '/mnt/3b42e9ce-1972-498b-9b96-13199979c333': Read-only file system
```

I also have tried to remount with writing permission but this did not work at all.

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1
```

or

```
sudo mount -o remount, uid=1000, gid=1000, rw /dev/sda1
```

The latest syntax is not understood by the system at all although you will find it in different forums. 
My software is in my home directory so should have the same rights as me.

What is most surprising me is that I lost the rights without having rebooted... While working on my software which was struggling since it could not write (I discovered lately the origin of the error)

Any help welcome

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -lah /mnt/3b42e9ce-1972-498b-9b96-13199979c333`?

Comment: I found the origin of the system getting read-only... I have errors on my drive. I captured them by doing 
    dmesg | grep "EXT4-fs error"

Comment: @Katu
ls -lah /mnt/3b42e9ce-1972-498b-9b96-13199979c333
total 40K
drwxrwxr-x 7 root   USER 4.0K Aug 24 09:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root   root   4.0K Aug 18 10:45 ..
drwxrwxr-x 7 USER USER 4.0K Aug 18 12:32 Consulting
drwxrwxr-x 3 USER USER 4.0K Aug 18 15:26 Himalayas
drwx------ 2 root   root    16K Aug 18 10:08 lost+found
drwxrwxr-x 2 USER USER 4.0K Aug 24 10:41 SNAP
drwx------ 5 USER USER 4.0K Aug 19 10:01 .Trash-1000

Comment: This may help https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently I think adding the `uid=1000` to the fstab mount line may solve the problem but not sure.

Comment: I never managed to get this uid option to work. It seems that this formating is not used anymore.

Comment: Besides I solved my disk errors and recreated a new journal with this 
`tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sda1`
`e2fsck -f /dev/sda1`
`tune2fs -j /dev/sda1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually mount all my non OS drives into /media. So you could mount your drive in /media/mydrive/ (change mydrive to anything you like).

```
sudo mkdir /media/mydrive
```

Get the UUID of your drive

```
sudo blkid
```

Make an entry in your fstab to mount your drive to /media/mydrive

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Add the entry, something like this

```
UUID=<the UUID from blkid>   /media/mydrive    ext4    errors=remount-ro    0   2
```

Take ownership of the mount point

```
sudo chown -R yourusername.yourusername /media/mydrive

sudo chmod +r /media/mydrive
```

Reboot

Comment: OK, 
I have altered a bit your suggestions:
I have unmounted the drive from mnt first
I have mounted in /media/<USER>/<DRIVE> with fstab because I guess it is the way it is done these days.
I had to redo the chown after reboot because I was not owner.
I now have to wait to see if I will loose ownership again.
Thanks

Comment: Although there were some errors on the drive, this solution worked. at some point. But unfortunately,  it switched to read-only again while I was cleaning the drive from unwanted files before the backup. Here the error in dmesg`EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:758: group 450, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 32768 vs 0 free clusters`
`Aborting journal on device sda1-8.`
`EXT4-fs (sda1): Remounting filesystem read-only`

Comment: Unmount the drive and perform a filesystem check. sudo fsck /dev/sda1.